# Get configuration flags that was setted before Qt compilation

Tags: qt, build

I have builded Qt.

Is it possible to get configuration flags that was setted before compilation? 
Such as icu or directwrite flags:

```
configure --icu --directwrite
```

Comment: do you have config.log written after configure? These flags may be written in it

Comment: @demonplus yes, I have 4 config.log files in qtimageformats, qtconnectivity, qtlocation and qtmultimedia folders. They not contains configure flags.